# Hard disk failure or about to fail Intel RST software RAID-1 volume event log

Tags: windows, software-raid, windows-event-log, eventviewer

If any one of the two Hardisk of Intel rapid Storage Technology(IRST) Software RAID-1 is about to fail or already failed, then what event will write in event viewer log and what is the Event ID for that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here in step 5:
http://www.whiz-tech.com/blog/2013/01/01/how-to-setup-e-mail-alerts-for-intel-ichr-raid-failure-monitor-applies-to-windows-2008-server-windows-7/

> Intel Storage Matrix Manager: Under “When a Specific Event is Logged”
>   screen select “Application” under Log Dropdown, “IAANTmon” as Source
>   and type “7202” in Event ID then click Next

Comment: Link-only answer are discouraged. I've edited you answer with relevant data from the link.